# Yet Another "Use of unassigned local variable 'whatever' " question

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, language-design

This is something that I have wondered about for a while now. I have browsed a bunch of questions containing the error below in their title but couldn't find one that explains this case.

First look at this example:

```
private void test() {
    string errorMessage;
    bool isOK = SomeClassWithBusinessRules.VerifySomeStuff(idOfStuffToVerify, ref errorMessage);
    if (!isOK)
        throw new BusinessException(errorMessage ?? "Some error occured.");
}
```

If you compile this the compiler will complain with this message:

> Error 2   Use of unassigned local variable 'errorMessage'

Changing the variable initializer to `null` will make it go away.

This will compile:

```
private void test() {
    string errorMessage = null;
    bool isOK = SomeClassWithBusinessRules.VerifySomeStuff(idOfStuffToVerify, ref errorMessage);
    if (!isOK)
        throw new BusinessException(errorMessage ?? "Some error occured.");
}
```

So why do we get the compilation error?

Comment: I think the `int` in `(int idOfStuffToVerify, ref ...)` is a typo, please correct.

Comment: Wow never had a question answered so fast and by two top SO'ers... Thanks!

Comment: "two top SO'ers"? No need to knock us lesser mortals!!   ;-)

Comment: True, make that "by only top SO'ers" :-) I only dream of a rep > 10K

Comment: +1: for a wonderful question that called upon an elite league of answers. @Peter: you already noticed :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you pass it to `VerifySomeStuff`, you are specifying `ref` but it does not yet have a value. That is not legal, as `VerifySomeStuff` could choose to read the value, which does not have a defined value at this point. Assigning `null` satisfies the definite assignment requirement. An alternative would be `out`:

```
string errorMessage;
bool isOK = SomeClassWithBusinessRules.VerifySomeStuff(id, out errorMessage);
if (!isOK)
    throw new BusinessException(errorMessage ?? "Some error occured.");
```

which would be legal (but requires changes to `VerifySomeStuff`, since the signature must be changed and it is now **required** to assign a value to the parameter before exit (unless an exception occurs)). From the code shown, it you might choose for `VerifySomeStuff` to assign `null` to the parameter if there is no error.

Of course, if the bool and string then *duplicate* the "was there a problem" purpose, you could also use:

```
string errorMessage = SomeClassWithBusinessRules.VerifySomeStuff(id);
bool isOK = errorMessage == null;
```

Answer (score 13):

You get the compilation error because a variable used as a `ref` argument has to be definitely assigned beforehand. If you change the method to use an `out` parameter instead, it'll be fine:

```
bool isOK = SomeClass.VerifySomeStuff(id, out errorMessage);
```

Note that this requires a change to `VerifySomeStuff` too, to make it an `out` parameter. The method would then have to definitely assign a value in any "normal" return path - so that by the time the method returns normally, `errorMessage` is definitely assigned.

See sections 10.6.1.2 and 10.6.1.3 details of `ref` and `out` parameters respectively.

Answer (score 6):

You are passing `errorMessage` by `ref`. This has in/out semantics. In other words, the protocol is that recipient can expect the object to have been initialised, which you did not do.

It seems as though you simply want `out` semantics. Change `VerifySomeStuff` to use `out` rather than `ref` for `errorMessage`, and also change the calling code to use `out`.

Note that when you pass using `out`, the callee is not allowed to read until the object has been initialized. The callee also has the responsibility of performing that inialization before returning.

Answer (score 5):

You can also correct the 'error' by changing the method to

```
 SomeClassWithBusinessRules.VerifySomeStuff(int idOfStuffToVerify, 
            out string  errorMessage);
```

When you use `out` the burden shifts to the method, it will not compile unless you make an assignment to the errorMessage parameter.

Answer (score 2):

When passing a `ref` argument, one of the things the called code can do is re-point the `ref` argument variable to a new location i.e. update its reference. In order for this to happen, the variable must point to something in the first place, therefore it must be assigned, even if this is just to `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Your question (why does the compiler complain) has already been answered by others. I would, however, suggest that you reconsider your design:

```
bool isOK = SomeClassWithBusinessRules.VerifySomeStuff(idOfStuffToVerify, ref errorMessage);
if (!isOK)
    throw new BusinessException(errorMessage ?? "Some error occured.");
}
```

Since `errorMessage` is only needed when an error occurs, why do you need the extra return value? You could shorten this to:

```
string error = SomeClassWithBusinessRules.VerifySomeStuff(idOfStuffToVerify);
if (error != null)
    throw new BusinessException(error);
}
```

(Of course, then you don't have the "Some error occured" case anymore. But showing "useless" error messages is bad practice anyway.)

In fact, if the error is an *exceptional circumstance* (i.e., something that's not part of the regular control flow but rather something indicating a data or logic error), it might make sense to move the exception *inside* VerifySomeStuff:

```
// no return value
SomeClassWithBusinessRules.VerifySomeStuff(idOfStuffToVerify);

class SomeClassWithBusinessRules {
    void VerifySomeStuff(int id) {
        ...
        if (someCondition)
            throw new BusinessException(error);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, these are very valid arguments you have, and I realy appreciate you taking the time to write them down! I used this approach because the errors coming out of the method are part of the flow. When this is called from a UI, we show the user a message. If it goes wrong in a batch we throw an exception, etc. And because exceptions are much more expensive than an out/ref variable, this seemed like the way to go. Mind you that the case in my question is not an extract of production code, the errors are much more clear there :-)

Comment: @Peter: I see, thanks for the clarification. Yes, what you write makes sense.

Comment: @Peter: have you considered then returning your own custom type from VerifySoemStuff instead of a simple bool? You could create a class that contains both a success/failure bool, and a error message in case of failure, and anything else you can think off. Then VerifySoemStuff returns an instance of this class.

Comment: @ShellShock: There are indeed good arguments for creating a custom class in this case. It would definitely be cleaner. It would however also create some overhead as it would be another class to manage and as Heinzi said, returning one string would be sufficient to know if something went wrong. So I'm going with the `string error = SomeClassWithBusinessRules.VerifySomeStuff(idOfStuffToVerify);` approach :-)